# Compare all columns to each other one by one in a smart way

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

There are variables `x`, `y`, `z`. I want to filter any of them have no huge gap (the gap less then 5%). Below code can simulate, but if I want more variables for comparing, the code will be boring. Is there any smart way for this? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
  select(x, y, z) %>%
  filter(abs((x - y)/ max(x, y)) < 0.05,
         abs((x - z)/ max(x, z)) < 0.05,
         abs((y - z)/ max(y, z)) < 0.05)
```

Comment: Perhaps: `sapply/mapply/map` + `combn(selected_vars, 2L)` + short self-written function to get the inputs correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `combn` + `rowMeans` like below

```
diamonds %>%
    filter(
        rowMeans(
            combn(
                select(., x, y, z),
                2,
                \(v) abs(v[[1]] - v[[2]]) / max(unlist(v)) < 0.05
            )
        ) == 1
    )
```

or a base R option using `subset` + `Reduce` + `combn`

```
subset(
    diamonds,
    Reduce(
        `&`,
        combn(
            list(x, y, z),
            2,
            \(v) abs(v[[1]] - v[[2]]) / max(unlist(v)) < 0.05,
            simplify = FALSE
        )
    )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2,023 × 10
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
 2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
 3  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
 4  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
 5  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
 6  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
 7  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
 8  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
 9  0.3  Good      J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
10  0.23 Ideal     J     VS1      62.8    56   340  3.93  3.9   2.46
# ℹ 2,013 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

## Benchmark

```
f1 <- function() {
    diamonds %>%
        filter(
            rowMeans(
                combn(
                    select(., x, y, z),
                    2,
                    \(v) abs(v[[1]] - v[[2]]) / max(unlist(v)) < 0.05
                )
            ) == 1
        )
}


f2 <- function() {
    subset(
        diamonds,
        Reduce(
            `&`,
            combn(
                list(x, y, z),
                2,
                \(v) abs(v[[1]] - v[[2]]) / max(unlist(v)) < 0.05,
                simplify = FALSE
            )
        )
    )
}

microbenchmark(
    f1 = f1(),
    f2 = f2(),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent",
    times = 50L
)
```

shows

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f1 25.91684 23.46633 17.96225 22.78245 19.55927 7.241132    50
   f2  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000 1.000000    50
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a list of condition expressions, and inject it into `filter()` with `!!!` operator.

```r
nms <- diamonds %>% select(x, y, z) %>% names()

# Use stringr::str_glue_data / glue::glue_data
conds <- lapply(str_glue_data(data.frame(t(combn(nms, 2))),
                              "abs(({X1}-{X2})/max({X1},{X2}))<0.05"), str2lang)

diamonds %>%
  filter(!!!conds)
```

###### Output

```
# # A tibble: 2,023 × 10
#    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#  3  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#  4  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#  5  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#  6  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#  7  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#  8  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#  9  0.3  Good      J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
# 10  0.23 Ideal     J     VS1      62.8    56   340  3.93  3.9   2.46
# ℹ 2,013 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

where `conds` is a list of calls

```r
# [[1]]
# abs((x - y)/max(x, y)) < 0.05
# 
# [[2]]
# abs((x - z)/max(x, z)) < 0.05
# 
# [[3]]
# abs((y - z)/max(y, z)) < 0.05
```

---

#### Benchmark on a larger dataset

```
Unit: relative
    expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
  Darren  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000    50
  jay.sf  1.634272  1.792466  1.714295  1.56970  1.652166  2.313737    50
 Thomas1 14.692111 14.537339 12.906745 12.44955 12.554815 10.956666    50
 Thomas2 14.475949 14.427519 12.857807 12.40311 12.398392 11.138774    50
      RB 93.001529 92.045358 82.934210 78.32732 78.497791 77.335309    50
```

With the following code, there should be 633 rows retained out of 10,000 rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(matrixStats); library(RcppAlgos)
library(microbenchmark)

# 10,000 x 100
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e6, mean = 100, sd = 2), 1e4, 1e2))

# Select V1 to V20 to generate all column pairs
nms <- paste0('V', 1:20)

smrt_comp <- \(data, cmpv, thr=.05) {
  colSums2(comboGeneral(cmpv, 2, FUN=\(x) {
    m <- as.matrix(data[, x])
    abs(rowDiffs(m)/max(m)) < thr
  }, FUN.VALUE=array(, nrow(data)))) == length(cmpv)
}

gap <- function(data) {
  x <- data[[1]]
  y <- data[[2]]
  abs((x - y)/max(x, y))
}

max_gap <- 0.05

microbenchmark(
  Darren = {
    conds <- lapply(str_glue_data(data.frame(t(combn(nms, 2))),
                                  "abs(({X1}-{X2})/max({X1},{X2}))<0.05"), str2lang)
    df %>%
      filter(!!!conds)
  }, jay.sf = {
    df[smrt_comp(df, nms), ]
  }, Thomas1 = {
    df %>%
      filter(
        rowMeans(
          combn(
            df[nms], 2,
            \(v) abs(v[[1]] - v[[2]]) / max(unlist(v)) < 0.05
          )
        ) == 1
      )
  }, Thomas2 = {
    subset(
      df,
      Reduce(
        `&`,
        combn(
          df[nms], 2,
          \(v) abs(v[[1]] - v[[2]]) / max(unlist(v)) < 0.05,
          simplify = FALSE
        )
      )
    )
  }, RB = {
    df %>% 
      select(all_of(nms)) %>%
      combn(m = 2L, gap, simplify = FALSE) %>%
      map_dfc(\(x) x < max_gap) %>%
      mutate(keep = rowSums(.) == ncol(.)) %>%
      bind_cols(df) %>%
      filter(keep) %>%
      select(-seq_len(choose(length(nms), 2)), -keep)
  }, times = 50, check = NULL, unit = "relative"
)
```

Answer (score 8):

This one, benefiting from C++, should run fast.

```
> smrt_comp <- \(data, cmpv, thr=.05) {
+   matrixStats::colSums2(RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(cmpv, 2, FUN=\(x) {
+     m <- as.matrix(data[, x])
+     abs(matrixStats::rowDiffs(m)/max(m)) < thr
+   }, FUN.VALUE=array(, nrow(data)))) == length(cmpv)
+ }
> diamonds[smrt_comp(diamonds, c('x', 'y', 'z')), ]
# A tibble: 2,023 × 10
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
 2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
 3  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
 4  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
 5  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
 6  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
 7  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
 8  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
 9  0.3  Good      J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
10  0.23 Ideal     J     VS1      62.8    56   340  3.93  3.9   2.46
# ℹ 2,013 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

*Data:*

```
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
```

Comment: Nice answer! You could check the benchmark part in my answer.  @Rui's and my outputs are equal, both retain 633 rows, but different from yours. Any idea?

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thx. Hmm good question; first, I was tricked because I thought `max(x, y)` makes row maximums (probably intended by OP??) but it doesn't. Finally I compared my`2,013 more rows` with Rui's and was happy.

Comment: @DarrenTsai PS: for the benchmark, I found that `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` has a `parallel=` option. Might be interesting how it performs in your benchmark.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way.

- Write a function `gap` to compute the relative distances;
- apply the function to each combination of columns two by two;
- now find which of these gaps are within the allowed maximum gap and put the logical results in a tibble binding by columns (`map_dfc`);
- `rowSums` will find how many rows are all `TRUE` and compare this to the number of columns creating the new column `keep`;
- bind with the original data set, filter the values to keep and clean up.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

gap <- function(data) {
  x <- data[[1]]
  y <- data[[2]]
  abs((x - y)/max(x, y))
}

max_gap <- 0.05

diamonds %>% 
  select(x, y, z) %>%
  combn(m = 2L, gap, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  map_dfc(\(x) x < max_gap) %>%
  mutate(keep = rowSums(.) == ncol(.)) %>%
  bind_cols(diamonds) %>%
  filter(keep) %>%
  select(-(1:4))
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`
#> • `` -> `...3`
#> # A tibble: 2,023 × 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#>  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  3  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#>  4  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  5  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#>  6  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#>  7  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#>  8  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#>  9  0.3  Good      J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
#> 10  0.23 Ideal     J     VS1      62.8    56   340  3.93  3.9   2.46
#> # ℹ 2,013 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05</sup>

---

To make the code more general purpose use a vector of columns to select. This will avoid hard coding the columns to discard at the end of the pipe.

```
cols_to_process <- c("x", "y", "z")

diamonds %>% 
  select(all_of(cols_to_process)) %>%
  combn(m = 2L, gap, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  map_dfc(\(x) x < max_gap) %>%
  mutate(keep = rowSums(.) == ncol(.)) %>%
  bind_cols(diamonds) %>%
  filter(keep) %>%
  select(-seq_len(choose(length(cols_to_process), 2)), -keep)
```

Comment: Nice answer! The last line should be `select(-seq_len(choose(length(nms), 2)), -keep)`

Comment: @Mark You are right. I loaded the data set before loading tidyverse, that's why it's there. Will edit.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Right, thanks! Edited.